# Sending mail via local IIS smtp server from ASP.NET core app silently fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

UPDATE: This turned out to be simple operator error - I failed to read the log file properly, which did indicate successful delivery on the IIS level.

Turns out that mails to this particular test address were blocked silently for unknown reasons unrelated to dotnet or IIS, by Gmail. Very sorry for posting something with such a simple solution and thanks to those that replied with helpful advice.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have a Windows server with IIS SMTP server installed.

I'm trying to send mails from my ASP.NET Core app with this code:

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "127.0.0.1";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

The code doesn't throw an exception, there is nothing in Windows error logs, nothing is logged to SMTP logs. It just fails silently.

The result of the Send() method is just the message itself, no error message or anything else helpful.

I tried in IIS to configure the SMTP Server but doesn't help.

I also tried other options like UseDefaultCredentials and to have it make a file in the Drop folder - in that case it says "not supported."

This exact same code works perfectly fine from my ASP.NET Standard app on the same server.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn303411(v=ws.11) "SMTP and associated management tools" are considered deprecated, so you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Just for fun: could you try to set the IP to a "false" IP address or port? Just to provoke an error or see if that still "succeeds"...

Comment: You should probably show how and where you have tried to set up SMTP settings. An option is to hardcode the settings as shown here: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/#using-smtp. I know it's not a permanent solution, but at least it eliminates the potential error of not being able to require the config.

Comment: Does it work when you run it in a development environment? Or does sending mail only fail when deployed to IIS?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be simple operator error - I failed to read the log file which indicated successful delivery on the IIS level. The mails to this particular test address were blocked silently for unknown reasons by Gmail. Very sorry for posting something with such a simple solution and thanks to those that replied with helpful advice.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer when it is available to mark. It can help other community member in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.